# How to get xml from a cross-domain with JQuery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display currency information on my website. I can get currency from a website for free. I would like to display this information by putting the workload on user's browser.

I want to get xml with JSONP, parse it and display the currency with all JQuery. Here is my code below

```
function GetTodayCurrency() {
    $.get("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml", function (response) {
        alert(response.html)
    }, "jsonp");
}
```

But this gives me error. It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". I think it gives me this error because there quotation in the xml.

How can I do this proper way? Is it a good practice to put this workload to Javascript? Is it better to do it on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this plugin to do the Cross origin Request :
http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml',
  crossOrigin: true,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
    $('#container').text(res.responseText);
  }
});
```